# How to check file upload is success complete or not by using `_.writeAsBytes()`?

Tags: dart, dart-server

I am using the function below to upload a file.

`File fileResult = await file.writeAsBytes(byte, mode: FileMode.append);`

I test 2 cases by

1. Uploaded `1.png` in the empty folder.
2. Uploaded `1.png` in the folder that already has `1.png`.

These results are the same!
But case 2 can't upload because this file name already exists and I use the `FileMode.append` method.
The `fileResult.isAbsolute` is always false I don't know why.

I can check by using the `await file.exists()` before uploading or using a unique file name. But I want to know how to check the upload by using `_.writeAsBytes()` is a success or not.

Comment: Is your `file` object a reference the already existing `1.png` file? Or is the `1.png` created, then uploaded to that directory?

Comment: The situation looks like the `1.png` already exists in the folder. Assume 2 users send an image from the flutter app simultaneously and these images have the same name. When these images are sent to the dart server, The server will upload an image of the first user. Then upload an image of the second user but this was not successful. I want a signal that tells me this upload was not a success.